# Javascript For Display Previous Day From Given Date

Tags: javascript, date

I have From-Date, To-Date, and Total-Days...if i have a From-Date and Total-Days then i have to calculate To-Date automatically
I Used The Following method to get the To-Date day

`var FromDate = $("#FromDate").val();
var TotalDays = $("#txtDays").val();
FromDate.setDate(parseInt(FromDate.getDate()) + parseInt(NoOfDays));
var dd = FromDate.getDate()-1;`

This Will Not Work For Day 1 of every month.....Since It Returns 0
How To Handle This Situation or help me to solve this in another way....Thanx In Advance

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve, then maybe it will be easier for us to help you out better

Comment: Not related to your question, but it is a very bad idea to reassign variables holding built-ins. After you run `Date = ...`, you lose access to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: I think he's trying to get 08-19-2018 in this case

Comment: `var Date=new Date` think what this does! You are overwriting the `Date` object with an instance of Date - will cause issues ... look into d.setDate ... hint, it doesn't matter if you set the date to 0, Date object is smart

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var d = new Date('08-20-2018');
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
alert(d.getDate());
```

Date object is smart enough to know what to do if you set any of the "components" (month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond) outside of "normal" range - it does the maths for you

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know the previous date, you can always subtract the 24hours from the epoch time and then convert it back to date object and get the date like:

`new Date(new Date('08-01-2018').getTime() - 24*3600000).getDate()`

1. `new Date('08-01-2018').getTime()` will give you the epoch time of the date you want previous date from
2. 24*3600000 is subtracting the 24 milliseconds from the epoch
3. After subtracting the value you get the previous day epoch and using the `new Date()` constructor you are getting the Date object again
4. On this new date object you can call `getDate()` method to get the correct result of 31.

I have given date to Date constructor in `MM-DD-YYYY` format

Comment: Subtracting 24 hours is not a good idea as not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed.

Comment: yeah, my bad totally missed that case.